# Lowercase column names returned when using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, hibernate

I have a Javascript application that uses Java as a backend with Hibernate, Spring and MySQL. The problem is that even though I have capitalized column in my DB, as well as in my entity source I'm getting lowercase column names in the JSON returned from the backend.

Here's the model source :

```
package app.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect;

@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
@Table(name="resources")
public class Resource {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="Id")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="Name", nullable=false)
    private String Name;

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

And the returned JSON :

`{"data":[{"name":"Tom","id":8},{"name":"Mike","id":9},{"name":"Jerry","id":10},{"name":"Larry","id":11},{"name":"Tina","id":12},{"name":"Tony","id":15}],"success":true}`

Is this behaviour somehow overridable/configurable ? If anything more is needed I'll update the post with required data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the conventional output of Jackson based on the name of the getter methods.  Use the [@JsonProperty](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation to override this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

try this..

```
@JsonProperty("Id")
public int getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.Id = id;
}
@JsonProperty("Name")
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.Name = name;
}
```